# How to align correctly element (text and image) inside the navbar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hope you are all fine. What I'm trying to do right now is to align the small icon with the text, I tried `d-inline` inside the `a` class. Still not working.
Another issue is the background color. The background color is just behind the `ul` tag and I don't know why. I put a `navbar-custom` class in the `nav` tag but it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```css
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #fafafc;
}

/* change the brand and text color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: #369d4a !important;
}
/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #369d4a !important;
}
/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #2b5c35 !important;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color:#369d4a;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    background-color:#369d4a;
}
.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
    background-color:#369d4a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="container navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-custom navbar-dark ">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggle btn_small_screen float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-item mx-4"> 
            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="#">
              <span data-feather="home"></span>
              TEST1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-4"> 
            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="#">
              <span data-feather="file"></span>
              TEST2
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-4"> 
            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="#">
              <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span>
              TEST22
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-4"> 
            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="#">
              <span data-feather="layers"></span>
              TEST3
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-4"> 
            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="#">
              <span data-feather="users"></span>
              TEST4
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-4"> 
            <a class="nav-link d-inline" href="#">
              <span data-feather="home"></span>
              TEST5
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    feather.replace()
  </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align elements in a navbar you can use flexbox

```
.element-class {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify: space-between; /* or center anyone that fits your design*/
   padding: 1rem;
}
```